# How do I know the branch or release tag after I sync data using repotool?

Tags: git, repository, repo

I was following https://gitlab.arm.com/arm-reference-solutions/arm-reference-solutions-docs/-/tree/master/docs/infra/rdn2 . The 'Download sources' link lead me to https://gitlab.arm.com/arm-reference-solutions/arm-reference-solutions-docs/-/blob/master/docs/infra/common/download-sources.rst .
My question is, when I gave these two commands,

```
repo init -u https://git.gitlab.arm.com/arm-reference-solutions/arm-reference-solutions-manifest.git -m <manifest-file-name> -b refs/tags/<RELEASE_TAG>
repo sync -c -j $(nproc) --fetch-submodules --force-sync
```

How can I know the <RELEASE_TAG> value after I sync the files? In git, I can use `git log` but I don't know how in repotool.

Answer (score 0):

In the top directory where you executed `repo init` and `repo sync` command, you can see .repo/manifests.git/config. In that file there is a section like

```
[branch "default"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/tags/RD-INFRA-2022.03.24
```

That is the branch you downloaded.